sql server client network utility - how to list the aliases?
there is something called sql server client network utility
it lives on
C:\Windows\System32 for 64 bits.
as you can see I have many aliases there, server, instance and ip address and port used for connectivity are all there.

I have here a great script by Hanna Vernon, that I have been using a lot, however, the aliases above configured on (generally the client machine) shown above take precedence, so
I would like a way to list those,best would be powershell, as in my case I dont even have sql server installed on that machine, it is a jenkins machine that connects to different sql server servers, but uses the settings defined on that sql server client network utility
/*
    Reads the instance's registry settings (via xp_instance_regread
    as opposed to xp_regread), to determine if the Dedicated 
    Aministrator Connection is configured to use the desired TCP 
    port number.

    2022-11-29  Hannah Vernon 
*/
SET NOCOUNT ON;
SET XACT_ABORT ON;

DECLARE @desired_dac_port   varchar(11)     = '1432';

IF NOT EXISTS
(
    SELECT 
        1 
    FROM 
        [sys].[configurations] sc
    WHERE  
        sc.[name] = N'show advanced options' 
        AND sc.[value] = 1
)
BEGIN
    PRINT N'Enabling "Show Advanced Options" configuration.';
    EXEC sys.sp_configure 
          @configname = 'show advanced options'
        , @configvalue = 1;
    RECONFIGURE;
END;

IF NOT EXISTS
(
    SELECT 
        1 
    FROM 
        [sys].[configurations] sc
    WHERE  
        sc.[name] = N'remote admin connections' 
        AND sc.[value] = 1
)
BEGIN
    PRINT N'Enabling Remote Dedicated Admin Connections.';
    EXEC sys.sp_configure 
          @configname = 'remote admin connections'
        , @configvalue = 1;
    RECONFIGURE;
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    PRINT N'Remote Dedicated Admin Connections are already enabled.';
END;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #dac_port;
CREATE TABLE #dac_port
(
      [value]   nvarchar(128)       NOT NULL
    , [data]    varchar(255)        NULL
);

INSERT INTO #dac_port
(
      [value]
    , [data]
)
EXEC sys.xp_instance_regread 
      @rootkey = N'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE'
    , @key = N'SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQLServer\SuperSocketNetLib\AdminConnection\Tcp'
    , @value = N'TcpDynamicPorts';

IF NOT EXISTS
(
    SELECT *
    FROM #dac_port dp
    WHERE dp.[value] = N'TcpDynamicPorts'
        AND dp.[data] = @desired_dac_port
)
BEGIN
    PRINT N'Setting Dedicated Admin Connection to use port ' + @desired_dac_port;

    EXEC sys.xp_instance_regwrite 
          @rootkey = N'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE'
        , @key = N'SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQLServer\SuperSocketNetLib\AdminConnection\Tcp'
        , @value_name = N'TcpDynamicPorts'
        , @type = N'REG_SZ'
        , @value = @desired_dac_port;
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    PRINT N'The dedicated admin connection is already configured on port ' + @desired_dac_port;
END;


this script is also top:
--Mark Storey-Smith

DECLARE 
    @StaticPort NVARCHAR(512)
    , @DynamicPort NVARCHAR(512)

EXEC xp_regread
    'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE'
    , 'SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL.1\MSSQLServer\SuperSocketNetLib\Tcp\IPAll'
    , 'TcpPort'
    , @StaticPort OUTPUT

EXEC xp_regread
    'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE'
    , 'SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL.1\MSSQLServer\SuperSocketNetLib\Tcp\IPAll'
    , 'TcpDynamicPorts'
    , @DynamicPort OUTPUT

SELECT
    @StaticPort AS StaticPort
    , @DynamicPort AS DynamicPort

Basically my question is:
how can I find out the aliases defined on sql server client network utility - reading the registry, either sql server or powershell?

In Powershell, it can be done easily with dbatools module.
This PowerShell module contains lots of cmdlets very useful for SQL Server management, including cmdlets to manage the aliases: Get-DbaClientAlias, New-DbaClientAlias, and Remove-DbaClientAlias
for more information: https://dbatools.io/aliases/
